# Htaccess won't work

Tags: server, apache2

I am trying to set up .htaccess on Ubuntu 15.04 with Apache 2.4.10.

**Some things I have tried so far**

- Modifying apache2.conf, from 'AllowOverride none' to 'AllowOverride All' for the var/www directory
- 'a2enmod rewrite' command will report this: Module rewrite already enabled

**How I fixed it**

What I was doing wrong was naming the file .httaccess instead of .htaccess, so pay attention to the name of the file.

**Testing method**

As outlined in other posts, you can just write junk lines in the .htaccess and if you are getting error 500 you are good to go.